Chromium Crashes
Chromium crashes, when launched via any crawler or when launched directly:
% DEBUG="selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection" python screenshot_mask.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/scripts/chromium_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010d4e16b8 chromedriver + 6149816
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010d4d8cda chromedriver + 6114522
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010cf65d5c chromedriver + 400732
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010cf9bef8 chromedriver + 622328
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010cf97e11 chromedriver + 605713
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010cfe29aa chromedriver + 911786
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010cfd5a53 chromedriver + 858707
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010cfa56d5 chromedriver + 661205
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010cfa5f6e chromedriver + 663406
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010d4a2cf0 chromedriver + 5893360
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010d4a84bc chromedriver + 5915836
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010d4848b4 chromedriver + 5769396
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010d4a8f89 chromedriver + 5918601
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010d475ec4 chromedriver + 5709508
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010d4c9008 chromedriver + 6049800
15  chromedriver                        0x000000010d4c91c7 chromedriver + 6050247
16  chromedriver                        0x000000010d4d888e chromedriver + 6113422
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81866b18b _pthread_start + 99
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff818666ae3 thread_start + 15

... same with Playwrite,.
I uninstalled, reinstalled chromium and it seems to be not corrupted:
% /Users/me/Library/Caches/ms-playwright/chromium-1117/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium --version

Chromium 125.0.6422.26

I am on Mac OsX 14.5 - with an Intel MacBook.
Any ideas how to solve that problem?
Thanks!
EDIT:
While writing a script that logs all various things, I found out that as soon as I set the env parameter, even if it's an empty dictionary, it works. Once I remove it, Chromium crashes again.
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

def run(playwright):
    # Incrementally adjust flags to identify the issue
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(
        headless=False,
        args=[
            '--enable-logging'
        ],
        env={
        }
    )
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://example.com")
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)

Is that expected? Here are more detailed logs of a crash (when I remove the env parameter): https://pastebin.com/02JUuMwR

Can you share your requirements.txt and the code/command you're running to cause the crash?

You should enable logging and look at the logs to find out why it's crashing

@ggorlen - I found out that is it related to env - please see the edited post
